# how to display wordpress tags and users who used them

Tags: wordpress, tags

Im using `$terms = get_terms( 'ad_tags');` to display tags from custom postype ,  It works well. Now I want to display the users who used them on the post. I'm coding a small plugin. e.g

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ){

    $term->name  // tag and users who used them 
}
```

How do you go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get user details who created the post by particular post id.

First of all, you can get user id of particular post by using `$author_id=$post->post_author;`

Then you can get other information of the user by using author_id with this function: `get_the_author_meta( string $field = '', int $user_id = false )`

You can pass `first_name`, `last_name`, `email` as a `$field` to get user information.

That's the way of getting user information of particular post.

I hope this will helpful for you.

Thanks.